# Check for date overlap in two different tables sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables one (A) contains holiday dates, the second (B) contains Departure, Arrival dates and Lead Time. What I want is to deduct from the lead Time the number of holidays.

So I want for each record of B to see how many of record of A is between Departure and Arrival date and then this deduct from lead time.

Is this feasible with SQL?

A pseudo SQL code:

```
Select 
    B.Lead time - SUM(CASE WHEN A.Holiday BETWEEN B.ArrDate AND B.DepDate 
                              then 1
                              ELSE 0
                        )
from A, B
```

Comment: It is possible but you may need to provide us the table structures and a sample to help you with the query

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

`FROM a, b` will give you a cross join (Cartesian product) which is probably not what you want. I think you want a `LEFT JOIN` and to `GROUP BY` the lead time:

```
SELECT b.lead_time - SUM( CASE WHEN a.holiday BETWEEN b.arrDate AND b.depDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
  FROM b LEFT JOIN a
    ON a.holiday BETWEEN b.arrDate AND b.depDate
 GROUP BY b.lead_time
```

That will work as long as `lead_time` is supposed to be unique in `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be more generalized :

```
SELECT 
A.DEP_DATE,A.ARR_DATE,(LEAD_TIME-X.CNT)  FROM A, 
(SELECT DEP_DATE,ARR_DATE, COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM A,B WHERE B.HOLIDAYS BETWEEN A.DEP_DATE AND A.ARR_DATE
GROUP BY DEP_DATE,ARR_DATE) X
WHERE
A.DEP_DATE=X.DEP_DATE 
AND 
A.ARR_DATE=X.ARR_DATE
```

Comment: works if you have more than 1 holidays in between dep date and arr date **syntax is based on oracle**

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to answer this question using a correlated subquery:

```
Select (B.Leadtime -
        (select count(*)
         from a
         where a.Holiday between b.ArrDate AND b.DepDate
        )
       )
from B;
```

Your holidays table should have an index on `holiday`.

Comment: Index on Holiday , what will it do ?

Comment: @etl_devs . . . It should improve the performance of this query and of most other queries on the table (unless the table is really small).